# Elegant way of validating permission in Android using MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

So, I'm using MVVM architecture with Repository pattern to make different API calls. 
I have a Repository called X, where I have different related API calls.

Before any of these calls are made, I would like to do validation. If that proceeds successfully, only then network request should be made.

```
fun getSomethingX(data: Data): Single<Data> {
    return if (validation(data)) {
        service.getSomethingX()
                .onErrorResumeNext(...)
                .map { ... ->
                    ...
                }
    } else {
        Single.just(null)
    }
}

fun getSomethingY(data: Data): Single<Data> {
    return if (validation(data)) {
        service.getSomethingX()
                .onErrorResumeNext(...)
                .map { ... ->
                    ...
                }
    } else {
        Single.just(null)
    }
 }
```

As you can see I might have many network request functions called `getSomething..()`. I see this as a boiler-plate code.

1. Is there some other way of dealing with validation (not only token validation but permission in general)? If so, can you show me an example?
2. Is it okay to do permission validation in the Repository level?
3. Maybe a better approach would be doing validation in `Interceptor`? But I don't see a clean way of canceling the request if validation does not pass.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach will be to keep the validation at repository level only and keeping your viewmodel dumb as possible. It’s very simply with [Kotlin’s Function literals with receiver](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver).

In your repository

```sh
fun getSomethingX(
   data: Data,
   onSuccess: (Single<Data>) -> Unit,
   onError: (String) -> Unit
) {
   if (validation(data)) {
      // Do the network call 
      onSuccess(//pass result)
   } else onError(“Invalid data”)
}
```

In your ViewModel

```sh
repository.getSomethingX(
   data,
   onSuccess = {
        //it will give you Single<Data>
        //Update the value
    },
    onError = {
        //Emit error to view 
    }
)
```